# Conditional where for postgres stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, condition

I want to create a conditional `where` clause using a PostgreSQL stored procedure.

This is my original stored procedure :

```
    select distinct 
    t.serialnumber as sn, 
    t.productid as tid,  
    t.merchantid as mid  
    from tbterminal as t
    ORDER BY idterminal ASC
```

I want to check if `p_mid`, `p_tid` and `p_sn` are null or empty; if not null and not empty, add an `and where` for every component.

This is what I've tried :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_list_terminal_datatable (
    p_mid varchar, 
    p_tid varchar,
    p_sn varchar,
    p_limit int, 
    p_offset int
) 
 RETURNS TABLE (
 sn VARCHAR,
     tid varchar,
     mid varchar
) 
AS $$
DECLARE
  data_where varchar := 'WHERE ';
BEGIN

 IF p_mid notnull and p_mid != '' THEN
   data_where := data_where || ' t.merchantid like '''%|| p_mid ||'%'' ';
 END IF;
 IF p_tid notnull and p_tid != '' THEN
   data_where := data_where || ' t.productid like '''%|| p_tid ||'%'' ';
 END IF;
 IF p_sn notnull and p_sn != '' THEN
   data_where := data_where || ' t.serialnumber like '''%|| p_sn ||'%'' ';
 END IF;
 RETURN QUERY 
 select distinct 
    t.serialnumber as sn, 
    t.productid as tid,  
    t.merchantid as mid  
    from tbterminal as t
    ORDER BY idterminal ASC 
    limit p_limit offset p_offset;
END; $$ 

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I know it doesn't work properly, so I need help on how to make the conditional where clause stored procedure in PostgreSQL work.

How would I have to write the stored procedure correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Boolean expressions, that return true, if a parameter is null or empty, otherwise the result of a `LIKE` operation.

```
...
SELECT DISTINCT
       t.serialnumber as sn,
       t.productid as tid,
       t.merchantid as mid
       FROM tbterminal as t
       WHERE (coalesce(p_mid, '') = ''
               OR t.merchantid LIKE '%' || p_mid || '%')
             AND (coalesce(p_tid, '') = ''
                   OR t.productid LIKE '%' || p_tid || '%')
             AND (coalesce(p_sn, '') = ''
                   OR t.serialnumber LIKE '%' || p_sn || '%')
       ORDER BY idterminal ASC
       LIMIT p_limit
       OFFSET p_offset;
...
```